# How to pass matrix in SESSION variable. php

Tags: php, arrays, session

I tried to pass a 2D matrix as `SESSION` variable.

test1.php:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
$a=5;
if($a>1)
{
$k=0;
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<0;$j++)
    {
        $mat[$i][$j]=$k++;
        echo $mat[$i][$j];
    }

}
print_r($mat);
$_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
$_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
$_SESSION["oned"]=$mat;
?>
<html>
 <a href="http://localhost/test2.php">Session variables are set"</a>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

The statements: 
`echo $mat[$i][$j];` is not showing any ouput and

The statements:

```
print_r($mat);
```

`$_SESSION["oned"]=$mat;` are showing: `"Notice: Undefined variable: mat"`

Comment: I am not sure if this for loop is functionally correct: `for($j=0;$j<0;$j++)` Because of this, the control never goes to that part of the code and the value of `$mat` is not getting set or displayed.

Comment: $j<0??? Seems to be a typo...

Comment: thats a huge typo error...how can i be so silly. thankyou for pointing it out.

Comment: you're dumping your matrix output **BEFORE** the `<html>` tag, which is illegal html. A browser is under no obligation to display stuff that's syntactically illegal.

Comment: @MarcB The whole point of using the session variable is to carry them forward to another page and navigating the that page through <h ref> .

Comment: irrelevant. you can use the session all you want, but where you have your print_r/echo statements causes you to do your output BEFORE the html document has started.

Comment: @MarcB I am not getting you here, are you saying that matrix output print)r/echo should come after html tag? but the program m coding needs to be displaying elements in this order.

Comment: @AzraMahrukh what you are doing is probably good for development/testing but may not be a good practice for Production environment.

Comment: @Maximus2012 Will keep it in mind, i am new to the language. What could be the alternative?

Comment: @AzraMahrukh at the very least, remove the `echo` `print_r` `var_dump` statements before going live. You can use `echo` if you are trying to display something that is relevant to the user and the application. Other than that, any debugging code should be removed from the production deployment. It may have possible security issues too.

Comment: @Maximus2012 Then all the content need to be displayed on the screen should be through html only? Informative indeed

Comment: @AzraMahrukh yes. That is good practice form a UI/UX view-point as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem: `for($j=0;$j<0;$j++)`.

It's good to initialize your variables first so you wont get that PHP notice.

Try:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
$a=5;
if($a>1)
{
    $mat = array();
    $k=0;
    for($i=0 ; $i<5 ; $i++)
    {
        for($j=0 ; $j<5 ; $j++)
        {
            $mat[$i][$j]=$k++;
            echo $mat[$i][$j];
        }

    }
    print_r($mat);
    $_SESSION["favcolor"] = "green";
    $_SESSION["favanimal"] = "cat";
    $_SESSION["oned"]=$mat;
    ?>
    <html>
    <a href="http://localhost/test2.php">Session variables are set"</a>
    </html>
<?php
}
?>
```